# Design patterns: How can concrete implementations select behaviours at run time?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I'm new to the terminology, so please correct me if I've phrased any part of my question wrong.

Here's the example that I'm thinking of: 
A file synchronization program that lets you pair 2 folders together, and specify options such as mirror the two folders, only copy contents one way, etc.
How would I specify at run time how each of these concrete implementations copy the files (eg, different types of encryption).

Here is what I'd somewhat like to accomplish:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnpIK.png

Do I have to make concrete implementations for each? ie MirrorAes, MirrorBlowfish, OnewayAes, etc?  Is there a better alternative?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that your diagram is showing it, the way you encrypt appears to be dependent on the way that you do synchronization. I doubt that this is the case (although I may be wrong).

If the way you sync is truly independent of the way you encrypt, switch from inheritance to composition. Make `FolderPair` an object that has a `SyncStrategy` and an `EncryptionStrategy`, like this:

```
class FolderPair {
    URI a, b;
    private final SyncStrategy syncStrategy;
    private final EncryptionStrategy cryptStrategy;
    public FolderPair(
        URI a
    ,   URI b
    ,   SyncStrategy syncStrategy
    ,   EncryptionStrategy cryptStrategy) {
        ...
    }
    public void sync() {
        syncStrategy.synchronize(a, b, cryptStrategy);
    }
}

interface SyncStrategy {
    void synchronize(URI a, URI b, EncryptionStrategy cryptStrategy);
}

interface EncryptionStrategy {
    byte[] encrypt(byte[] data);
}
```

Now you can configure your `FolderPair` objects with instances of `SyncStrategy` and `EncryptionStrategy`, mixing and matching them without creating combinatorial explosion:

```
FolderPair p1 = new FolderPair(aUri, bUri, new OneWyaSync(), new AesCrypt());
```

This design features two applications of the [*Strategy Pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) - one for the synchronization behavior, and the other one for the encryption.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks!  I have reworked my diagram to look like this:
http://i.imgur.com/vSIBF.png
I didn't think to put EncryptionStrategy into SyncStrategy, ie here
void synchronize(URI a, URI b, **EncryptionStrategy cryptStrategy**);
and here:
syncStrategy.synchronize(a, b, **cryptStrategy**);
Could you describe the thought process you took to come to that result? Or is it mostly related to experience?  Are there examples somewhere?
Thanks again!

Comment: @user1546985 Once you realize that you need to split the two strategies, your choices are limited: you either give one strategy to the other in the constructor, or you pass it to the method where it is needed. I liked the passing to method better, because I couldn't think of a reason why an instance of encryption strategy should be owned by a sync strategy, or why an instance of sync strategy should be owned by an encryption strategy.

Answer (score 0):

You've got orthogonal concerns - the sync type and the encryption. One way to approach this is the Strategy Pattern, where your concrete implementations of the synchronization classes aggregate an encryption class, and the synchronizers interact with an encryption interface, allowing "mix and match" encryption and synchronization without having a multiplier effect on the number of classes you write.

Answer (score 0):

You mean, you need an encryption strategy?

Use an abstract factory together with a set of strategies for encryption. In case you have multiple options, use a builder.

Let's say, you have a SHA1Encryption and a DESEncryption. Both implement an interface, say, GeneralEncryptionStrategy, and you have an EncryptionFactory, which takes a string (either "sha1" or "des") as an argument and creates an instance of the corresponding class.